# Zoom in/out on a point of a function:

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, zooming

I have taken a code on this site *(Edit/Guess by Manuel Kuehner: [Plotting several functions with TikZ/pgf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200354))*

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:4]
  \draw[very thin,color=gray] (-0.1,-1.1) grid (3.9,3.9);
  \draw[->] (-0.2,0) -- (4.2,0) node[right] {$x$};
  \draw[->] (0,-1.2) -- (0,4.2) node[above] {$f(x)$};
  \draw[color=red] plot (\x, \x) node[right] {$f(x) =x$};
  \draw[color=blue] plot (\x, { sin(\x r) }) node[right] {$f(x) = \sin x$};
  \draw[color=orange] plot (\x, { 0.05*exp(\x) })
    node[right] {$f(x) = \frac{1}{20} \mathrm e^{x}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:4]
  \draw[very thin,color=gray] (-0.1,-1.1) grid (3.9,3.9);
  \draw[->] (-0.2,0) -- (4.2,0) node[right] {$x$};
  \draw[->] (0,-1.2) -- (0,4.2) node[above] {$f(x)$};
  \draw[color=red] plot (\x, {-\x / 3 + 1/5}) node[right] {$f(x)$};
  \draw[color=blue] plot
    (\x, { 1/2 * \x + 1/2 - 1/2 * sqrt(5 * \x^2 + 2*\x + 1)})
    node[right] {$g(x)$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

and I would like to have a zoom with a magnifying glass on a generic point of the graph using only the coordinates. That is, fixing generic coordinates I wondered if there was a general command to view a particular of the graph. This is the result I would like to get.

[image]
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe link the source of the code that you copied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you are looking for the so-called `spy` feature of `tikz` (not `pgfplots`, but you can use it within `pgfplots`). In the `pgfplots` manual you find an example:

[image]

Here's a screenshot of the corresponding chapter for `pgf/tikz`:

[image]

```
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200354
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{spy} % <-- added

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    domain=0:4,
    spy using outlines={circle, magnification=4, size=2cm, connect spies}, % <-- added (pgf manual example)
    ]
  \draw[very thin,color=gray] (-0.1,-1.1) grid (3.9,3.9);
  \draw[->] (-0.2,0) -- (4.2,0) node[right] {$x$};
  \draw[->] (0,-1.2) -- (0,4.2) node[above] {$f(x)$};
  \draw[color=red] plot (\x, \x) node[right] {$f(x) =x$};
  \draw[color=blue] plot (\x, { sin(\x r) }) node[right] {$f(x) = \sin x$};
  \draw[color=orange] plot (\x, { 0.05*exp(\x) })
    node[right] {$f(x) = \frac{1}{20} \mathrm e^{x}$};

    \spy [red] on (1.6,0.3) in node [left] at (3.5,-1.25); % <-- added (pgf manual example)    
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:4]
  \draw[very thin,color=gray] (-0.1,-1.1) grid (3.9,3.9);
  \draw[->] (-0.2,0) -- (4.2,0) node[right] {$x$};
  \draw[->] (0,-1.2) -- (0,4.2) node[above] {$f(x)$};
  \draw[color=red] plot (\x, {-\x / 3 + 1/5}) node[right] {$f(x)$};
  \draw[color=blue] plot
    (\x, { 1/2 * \x + 1/2 - 1/2 * sqrt(5 * \x^2 + 2*\x + 1)})
    node[right] {$g(x)$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]